# ScrollView, ListView or RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am just starting with Android development.

For my project, I need to finalize on two things - regarding - feature, ease of implementation & maintainability (Actually, the functionality is - the user will enter a Youtube url & video name & that should be display as a new row in a List.)

1. The List

   Which one to choose?

   - ScrollView,
   - ListView or
   - RecyclerView

(I know, `RecycleView`  is the featured one - but does that selection be justified here - where we are just using limited functionality)

2. Data Format
   I will be storing the data using a service & which would be the suggestive format for retrieving - json, gson or Retrofit

Answer (score 2):

ScrollView - is just to add scrolling to your view. It's like a container (like LinearLayout).

If you choose between ListView and RecyclerView, just use RecyclerView with ViewHolder pattern - because it's more flexible.

Retrofit - is a library for, an example, REST API. And it's use JSON.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use scrollview wherever necessary. Things you need to  keep in mind  while using scrollview is, 
   i. Don't use Listview/Recyclerview/Gridview inside view Scrollview, because it have it's own scrollable functionality , you can specify which scrollbars you need either vertical/horizontal. 
   ii. **Recyclerview** -> Performance and usability, code wise it's easy to use, you can find lot of question related to item clickable inside listview row (Which is pain), recyclerview will be more helpful,you can add your own clickListener to anything you like. so Best.
2. **Retrofit** -> This parse your request and json to appropriate pojo model . Only Best available you should go with this. Saves your lot of time.